# check startup applications with a different user

Tags: users, startup-applications, user-profile

Is it possible to check the list of the startup applications for a specific user account by using another user account?

Both accounts are administrators.

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10.

I tried to search on google, but I found nothing about this topic.
I need to check if a specific application has been set as startup application for a specific user account.

EDIT:
Thanks to the suggestions, I was able to get the startup list applications list:

```
find ~/.config/autostart -user robodyne -ls
  5641238      4 drwx------   2 robodyne robodyne     4096 nov 19 14:28 /home/robodyne/.config/autostart
  5637055      4 -rw-rw-r--   1 robodyne robodyne      203 ott 14 16:43 /home/robodyne/.config/autostart/teamviewer.desktop
  5641240      4 -rw-rw-r--   1 robodyne robodyne      218 set 11 22:10 /home/robodyne/.config/autostart/snap-userd-autostart.desktop
  5641239      4 -rw-rw-r--   1 robodyne robodyne      204 nov 19 14:28 /home/robodyne/.config/autostart/Isola02.desktop
```

is it possible to remove a specific entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to get the list of startup applications of another user.
To do so, you must need to know the **username** and **password** of that user.
So, while you are using your account open terminal and type
`su username`
then terminal is waiting for you to type the password for that user.    
Given below command is used to get list of startup applications by the specific user.
`find /etc/init.d -user username -ls`
If you do not get the list then use given below command to get the list of  **autostart applications**.
`find ~/.config/autostart -user username -ls`

> Note:
>    replace `username` with the specific username

---

#### EDIT :

If you want to remove a specific application from `autostart` -
Suppose you want to remove `teamviewer.desktop` as shown in the list output then use.  
`rm -iv ~/.config/autostart/teamviewer.desktop`

here **-i** will prompt before every removal.
**-v** will explain what is being done.

Comment: May worth mentioning that the last find command has to be used after logging in as the other user. The ~ refers to home directory of the user under whom the find command runs. Ir just use full path like /home/johndoe/.config/autostart

Comment: It worked really fine!! Is it possible to remove a specific application?

Comment: I edited my first post in order to show the list of applications. Is it possible to remove only a specific list? Obviously, I can login as the correct user.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Type `echo ~` to get the current poiting directory and then  use `su username` after then by typing `echo ~`, you can see the poiting directory has changed from previous to new specific user. So what's problem ?

Comment: I don't know the meaning of your last post, however, I solved it, thank you a lot!

Comment: @MarcusBarnet Do you want to remove specific application from the `list` or from the `OS (Ubuntu)`?

Comment: From the list, so I just removed the `teamviewer.desktop` file inside the `autostart`  directory.

Comment: Okay, You can login again and it'll not automatically open.